# What is servers in Memcached exactly?

Tags: php, memcached

When we want to connect to memcached there is a parameter that specifies server address. Does this server part can be used just in clustered servers or can it be used in everyform we want? Could someone shed some light on the subject. I don't really know how to use this part. I always put `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in this part. What if I wanna add some servers later?

In the project wiki I saw the below part:

```
//in your configuration file: 

$MEMCACHE_SERVERS = array(
    "10.1.1.1", //web1
    "10.1.1.2", //web2
    "10.1.1.3", //web3
);


//at the 'bootstrapping' phase of your app somewhere:

$memcache = new Memcache();
foreach($MEMCACHE_SERVERS as $server){
    $memcache->addServer ( $server );
}
```

I'm missing something here! Soud they be clustered?
What does it mean when we say all of the servers should be on one network if you want to add servers to memcache?